# server side rendering in angular universal not showing fav icon

Tags: angular, angular-universal, server-side-rendering

I have an angular application that I want to make it an universal angular application.

The reason behind this to make my application more SEO friendly.

The followed the steps described in https://angular.io/guide/universal and I even reproduced the example in https://github.com/mappedinn/how-to-create-angular-univeral.

This was almost successful. The only issue is that the browser is not showing `favicon.ico` in the tab when running the application through the following commands:

```
npm run build:ssr
npm run serve:ssr
```

Refer to the picture below [image: FAVICON.ICO NOT DISPLAYED]

But, in case of running the application through the command `ng serve`, the favicon is available.

Please refer to the following pic:
[image: FAVICON.ICO DISPLAYED]

So, could you please help with this issue?

---

## Update 1

Since the folder `src/assets/` does not exist. It has been created and it includes now the file `favicon.ico`.

Building the SSR was correct (the command `npm run build:ssr`).

Serving the SSR generated an error (the command `npm run serve:ssr`)

```
> angular-io-example@1.0.0 serve:ssr /home/amine/docker-projects/how-convert-to-universal
> node dist/server

events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::4000
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1044:20)
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1367:14)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1408:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1492:7)
    at Function.listen (/home/amine/docker-projects/how-convert-to-universal/dist/server.js:44577:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/amine/docker-projects/how-convert-to-universal/dist/server.js:116:5)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/amine/docker-projects/how-convert-to-universal/dist/server.js:20:30)
    at Object.defineProperty.value (/home/amine/docker-projects/how-convert-to-universal/dist/server.js:69:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/amine/docker-projects/how-convert-to-universal/dist/server.js:72:10)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! angular-io-example@1.0.0 serve:ssr: `node dist/server`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the angular-io-example@1.0.0 serve:ssr script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/amine/.npm/_logs/2018-09-18T16_21_55_407Z-debug.log
```

## Update 2

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'run', 'serve:ssr' ]
2 info using npm@6.4.1
3 info using node@v8.10.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'preserve:ssr', 'serve:ssr', 'postserve:ssr' ]
5 info lifecycle angular-io-example@1.0.0~preserve:ssr: angular-io-example@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle angular-io-example@1.0.0~serve:ssr: angular-io-example@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle angular-io-example@1.0.0~serve:ssr: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle angular-io-example@1.0.0~serve:ssr: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/home/amine/docker-projects/how-convert-to-universal/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/apache/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7:/home/amine/anaconda3/bin:/home/amine/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/usr/local/apache/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7:/home/amine/anaconda3/bin:/home/amine/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/local/apache/hadoop-2.9.0/bin:/usr/local/apache/hadoop-2.9.0/sbin:/usr/local/apache/hadoop-2.9.0/bin:/usr/local/apache/hadoop-2.9.0/sbin
9 verbose lifecycle angular-io-example@1.0.0~serve:ssr: CWD: /home/amine/docker-projects/how-convert-to-universal
10 silly lifecycle angular-io-example@1.0.0~serve:ssr: Args: [ '-c', 'node dist/server' ]
11 silly lifecycle angular-io-example@1.0.0~serve:ssr: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle angular-io-example@1.0.0~serve:ssr: Failed to exec serve:ssr script
13 verbose stack Error: angular-io-example@1.0.0 serve:ssr: `node dist/server`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
14 verbose pkgid angular-io-example@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd /home/amine/docker-projects/how-convert-to-universal
16 verbose Linux 4.15.0-34-generic
17 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "serve:ssr"
18 verbose node v8.10.0
19 verbose npm  v6.4.1
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error angular-io-example@1.0.0 serve:ssr: `node dist/server`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the angular-io-example@1.0.0 serve:ssr script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Do you see the favicon being downloaded in the network ?

Comment: No. It is not coming...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a nice article for that https://medium.com/@maciejtreder/angular-server-side-rendering-with-ng-toolkit-universal-c08479ca688

A simple `ng add @ng-toolkit/universal` will convert the application to universal.

Extra: `ng add @ng-toolkit/serverless` for server side rendering

Answer (score 0):

make sure in your angular.json file you include it under the assets section

```
"assets": [
    // add any images paths here, or add to your assets folder and put folder path here
]
```

Comment: Run the finished example provided by angular.io: [https://angular.io/generated/zips/universal/universal.zip](https://angular.io/generated/zips/universal/universal.zip). It will be having the same problem!!!

Comment: hmm, can you show your angular.json file? also do you have to build using npm run build or can you use ng build? I'm not overly familiar with Angular uni

Comment: this is it: [https://github.com/mappedinn/how-to-create-angular-univeral/blob/master/angular.json](https://github.com/mappedinn/how-to-create-angular-univeral/blob/master/angular.json)

Comment: probably, some work is needed on the express.js server or on the webpack config O_o

Comment: have you tried including the favicon in the assets folder and then pointing path to that one instead of the glob? I believe the issue is the build changes the path when the favicon is included in the glob.

Comment: Give me 1 minute

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180284/discussion-between-amine-jallouli-and-fussinhussin).

Comment: I am quiet sure that thing could be solved in the webpack config but I am not familiar with webpack